# Generate exe from Python 3.6.1

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I generate .exe from python 3.6.1
I tried pyinstaller but it returns IndexError: tuple index out of range
also I tried py2exe and return IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Well perhaps than your program got a tuple and you access an index out of range?

Comment: pyinstaller is still not compatible with python 3.6, you should use python 3.5 , pyinstaller works like a charm

Comment: When you run it in pure python does it give the same error?